# Q: How do I check role in Vuex?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I trying to check role of user login in vue js, I'm using vuex for store, I want to check if the role of user or admin logged push to admin for role = 1 and role = 1 be push to user but something is wrong with vuex for me. And my role is role is 1 for admin and 0 for user login in database, I'm doing with laravel 7 for API and Vue

Can anyone help me?

store.js

```
state: {
        status: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
        user: {},
        role: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        auth_request(state){
            state.status = 'loading'
        },
        auth_succes(state, token, user,role){
            state.status = 'success'
            state.token = token
            state.user = user
            state.role = role
        },
        auth_error(state){
            state.status = 'error'
        },
        logout(state){
            state.status = ''
            state.token = ''
        },
    },
    actions: {
        login({commit}, user){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
                commit('auth_request')
                axios({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login', data: user, method: 'POST'})
                .then(res => {
                    const token = res.data.token
                    const user = res.data.user
                    const role = res.data.role
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
                    commit('auth_succes', token, user,role)
                    resolve(res)

                })
                .catch(err =>{
                    commit('auth_error')
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    reject(err)
                })
            })
        },
        register({commit}, user){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
                commit('auth_request')
                axios({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/m2/signIn', data: user, method: 'POST'})
                .then(res => {
                    const token = res.data.token
                    const user = res.data.user
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
                    commit('auth_succes', token, user)
                    resolve(res)

                })
                .catch(err =>{
                    commit('auth_error')
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    reject(err)
                })
            })
       }
```

Login.vue

```
methods: {
       login: function(){
           let email = this.email
           let password = this.password
           if(this.$store.state.role === 1 ){
               this.$store.dispatch('login',{email, password})

                   console.log('Admin logged');

           }else{
               console.log('User logged');
       }
```

The result show me is: User logged

Answer (score 0):

vuex mutations can accept two parameters, "mutation name" and "payload"

And you are trying to pass 4 parameters
`commit('auth_succes', token, user,role)`

You should use object to pass multiple parameters to vuex mutation

`commit('auth_succes', { token, user, role })`

Comment: Do you updated your auth_succes mutation so it can handle object payload ?

Comment: yes I have updated mutation already ! but if try this.$store.state.role == 1 || 'admin' it return Admin logged